# Matching two strings stored in different variables in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, file-read

I am new to node.js. I was practising a program to find a pattern in a string and extracting that part of line from the file. 
File as:

```
Something written in a file saved as filename.ext.
At a line, it contains a link.
import "https:\//www.hostname.com/$path"
```

I want to extract the link from any line in a file.
I was trying to match the pattern to get index no of 'h' in 'http' and extracting it further. Stuck at nm() as it isn't working on variable as parameter.

```
var url=require('url')
var fs = require('fs');
var find = require('find');
var findInFiles = require('find-in-files');
var LineReader = require('linereader');
var nm = require('nanomatch');
var sol=require('./../bin/sol-merger')
var dir = './merged/';
var pth=process.cwd()+'/'+dir+'newfile.sol'
var flag=0
if (!fs.existsSync(dir)){
fs.mkdirSync(dir);
}
fs.createReadStream(sol.abs_path).pipe(fs.createWriteStream(dir+'/newfile.sol'));

findInFiles.find({'term': "http", 'flags': 'ig'}, 'merged/', '.sol$').then(function(results) {
//console.log("here...")
for (var result in results) {
    var res = results[result];
    console.log('found "' + res.matches[0] + '" ' + res.count+ ' times in "' + result + '"')
    console.log(sol.fl+"    "+result)   
}
var lr=new LineReader(pth)
lr.on('error', function (err) {
    console.log(err);
    console.log("error")
    lr.close();
});
lr.on('line', function (lineno, line) {
    console.log(lineno + "   " + line);
    if(nm.contains(`$line`,'*"http**"*')){
        console.log("found")
    }
});
})
```

Comment: "I'm stuck at matching the pattern." Update the question with what you tried and what is not working.

Comment: Please update your question with your code attempt(s).

Comment: good now? But i just want to know how to get a link from a file. or any module to do that.

Comment: Indeed. I added an answer. It's very important to precisely give a small example and working code for community to answer. This makes it easier for anyone to attack the problem. For instance, with your original question, there was no way we could have known what all libraries you were using, and what anomaly was happening. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
findInFiles.find({'term': "http", 'flags': 'ig'}, 'merged/', '.sol$')
```

to

```
var regex = 'http.*?(?=\")'
findInFiles.find({term: regex, flags: 'g'}, 'merged/', '.sol$')
```

The regex matches http/https link till `"` is found at end of link, but doesn't capture `"` in group. `(?=\")` is positive lookahead match.

See regular expression's explanation and working example here - https://regex101.com/r/4RAr0Z/1

Comment: yeah. the link could be http or https but that I can manage. Thanks man. Cheers!

Comment: regex should be taking care of both http and https links - see - https://regex101.com/r/4RAr0Z/2

Comment: Man, i did it. Just not publicly. They are recorded. Privacy of my vote. :P

Answer (score 0):

I would use regex, e.g.:

```
//read in eg with fs module
var _test = 'import "https://www.github.com/xyz/abc.txt" \n import "https://www.github.com/xyz/xab.txt"';
var _reg = /["](.*?)["]/gm;
var _my_matches = _test.match(_reg);
console.log(_my_matches); //array with all matches
```

Please note, this is a minimal example. I recommend to test out your required regex setup at https://regex101.com/ (or something similar)